# How to change npm path

Tags: npm

All my npm packages work, but my npm package list shows empty. I am sure this is issue with a path but not sure how to fix it.

Which gulp gives me >

```
[~] ruby-2.2.3 $ which gulp
/usr/local/bin/gulp
```

Which npm gives me >

```
[~] ruby-2.2.3 $ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

npm list gives me >

```
[~] ruby-2.2.3 $ npm list
/Users/kimmo
└── (empty)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing packages that are installed globally with those locally.  The paths for `gulp` and `npm` look like the global install locations.  Packages you install locally will be found under a `node_modules` folder in the root of your project.

You can confirm this by comparing the results from:

- `npm ls -g --depth=0`
- `npm ls --depth=0`

The first command will show the globally installed packages.  The second will show the local packages.

At the top of the resulting output, each shows the directory where the global or local install is located.

Finally, the `--depth=0` flag only shows the packages that were required and not the dependencies of those packages (and those packages, etc).  I find that most of the time, that's all I care about.  If you agree, you can easily make this a default with `npm config set depth 0` or by editing your `.npmrc` file in your home directory.

So!  My guess is that you installed gulp with the `-g` flag but you haven't installed anything locally (with no flag, so to speak).  That's why there's a difference between what `which` is showing and `npm ls` is showing.

Comment: Thanks Mathew! Tested and you are spot on!